# Switching to Android 1.6 shrinks url images

Tags: android

So basically I had to switch from 1.5 to 1.6 to add in Mobfox. As soon as I did this all the images being called by url are now being displayed much smaller. Is there a way to counter act this because it is kind of annoying and they were just the right size before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you'll have to rework your images due to the different way that Android v1.6 onwards handles differing screen sizes and resolutions.

From [Strategies for Android 1.5](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-support-1.5.html)

> **All applications written for Android 1.5 or earlier, by default, support only the baseline HVGA screen** used on the T-Mobile G1 and similar devices, which is normal screen size and medium density (mdpi). **Android 1.6 introduced support for different screen configurations** and added APIs that allow applications to control how they operate on different screens, using alternative resources for different screen configurations.

See this article for supporting different screens for v1.6 onwards...[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks. Ya I know it handles them differently and I am used to working with them, but I have the images set to wrap_content and considering the images are the same size on a website I would think they would still fit about the same way. Not used to working with images being called from the net so not exactly sure how to go about readjusting them.